# JQUERY UI sortable для динамичных(новых) элементов

Tags: jquery

Использую  JQUERY UI sortable. 
У меня генерируются в html  новые элементы, которые должны обрабатываться этим плагином.

Но они не обрабатываются. 
Я знаю, что дело в том, что они - это новые элементы. Обычно я обрабатываю таким образом 
`$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){ });`
и все окей у меня ..

А вот как сделать, чтобы именно плагин реагировал, не пойму. 
Вот конфиг плагина в html и там же ссылка на него:

```js
 
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
 cursor: "move",
 containment:'#sortable',
 revert:'true',
 handle:'.img_preview img'
 //documentation http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/JQuery_UI
 });
  });
```

Может, кто подскажет, как можно реализовать .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
        var sortable_opts = {
            cursor: "move",
            containment:'#sortable',
            revert:'true',
            //handle:'.img_preview img'
            //documentation http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/JQuery_UI
        };
        $("#sortable").sortable(sortable_opts);
        $(document).on("click",'#sortable',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).sortable(sortable_opts);
        });
 });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh4j63zq/)

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. Попробовать `$("#sortable").sortable("refresh" );` после добавления новых элементов.
2. Обернуть сам `sortable` в функцию.

   ```
   function doSort(){
       $("#soratable").sortable({
           ...
       });
   }
   ```

   и вызывать эту функцию `doSort()` после добавления нового контента.